# Right shift with zero fill operator in Java (>>>) only working with "int" not "byte"

Tags: java, int, byte, bit-shift, zerofill

I write a program in Java to use the right shift with zero fill (>>>) operator.
For the following program everything is good.

```
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                int b = -1;
                int c = b>>>2;
                System.out.println(b);
                System.out.println(c);
        }
}
```

Output is:

```
-1
1073741823
```

Everything is good in the above program. But if I write the same program for byte:

```
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                byte b = -1;
                byte c = (byte)(b>>>2);
                System.out.println(b);
                System.out.println(c);
        }
}
```

Output is:

```
-1
-1
```

It looks like working of ">>" operator rather than ">>>". My expected output was:

```
-1
63
```

Please explain the concept behind it.

Comment: The type of  `(b >>> 2)` is `int`.  So the zeroes end up being in much more significant bits than the two leading bits of a `byte`.

Comment: @David Wallace   But b is a byte. The operator is operating on byte. Although after operation it returns int, but before that it becomes 63. Although 63 in int. May be I am wrong, but I am confused..

Comment: Why do you say that "before" the operation it becomes 63?  Nothing is 63 until after the operation.  The `>>>` operator acts on `int` expressions, not `byte`, so the conversion happens before the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Before each operation Java converts byte, short or char operand (variable, or constant both) to int. Then after the operation executes.

```
byte b = 2, c = 3;
byte d = b * c; //Compilation error
```

Before multiplication operation both b and c gets converted in int. so the result was int. We tried to store int in byte d, which results compilation error.

Same thing happens with shift operators too.

```
int c = b>>>2;
```

First b gets converted int. Then shift operation occurs with int. Final result is an int. As  David Wallace says: "So the zeroes end up being in much more significant bits than the two leading bits of a byte".